# System.Data.SqlClient not found in Repository Constructor

Tags: .net-core, dapper

I'm trying to build a data layer in my application based on a .NET Core class library using Dapper.  The data classes look like this:

```
//FieldRepository.cs
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
public class FieldRepository :  IRepository<TblField>
{
    private IDbConnection connection;

    public FieldRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TblField> GetAll()
    {
        return connection.GetAll<TblField>();
    }
}

//IRepository.cs
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}

//TblField
public class TblField
{
    public string FieldText { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then I tried to run a test against these classes as below:

```
public void ThereShouldBeFields()
{
    var repo = new FieldRepository("valid connection string");
    var fields = repo.GetAll();
    fields.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

When I ran this test, I got a FileNotFound exception at the FieldRepository constructor for System.Data.SqlClient, version 4.2.0.0, which is installed in the data layer project.

I know I'm missing something simple here, but what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was because the reference needed to be added to both the Test project and the Data layer project.

The more you know!